# Coq: adding a "strong induction" tactic

Tags: coq

"Strong" (or "complete") induction on the natural number means that when proving the induction step on n, you can assume the property holds for any k

```
Theorem strong_induction:
forall P : nat -> Prop,
(forall n : nat, (forall k : nat, (k < n -> P k)) -> P n) ->
forall n : nat, P n.
```

I have managed to prove this theorem without too many difficulties. Now I want to use it in a new tactic, strong_induction, which should be similar to the standard "induction n" technique on the natural numbers. Recall that when using "induction n" when n is a natural number and the goal is P(n), we get two goals: One of the form P(0) and the second of the form P(S(n)), where for the second goal we get P(n) as assumption.

So I want, when the current goal is P(n), to get one new goal, also P(n), but the new assumption "forall k : nat, (k < n -> P(k)))".

The problem is I don't know how to do it technically. My main problem is this: Suppose P is a complex statement, i.e.

```
exists q r : nat, a = b * q + r
```

with a b : nat in the context; how can I tell Coq to do the strong induction on a and not on b? simply doing "apply strong_induction" results in

```
n : nat
H0 : forall k : nat, k < n -> exists q r : nat, a = b * q + r
______________________________________(1/2)
exists q r : nat, a = b * q + r
______________________________________(2/2)
nat
```

where the assumption is useless (since n does not relate to a) and I have no idea what the second goal means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, to `apply strong_induction` you need to `change` the conclusion of the goal so that it better matches the conclusion of the theorem.

```
Goal forall a b, b <> 0 -> exists ! q r, a = q * b + r /\ r < b.
change (forall a, (fun c => forall b, b <> 0 -> exists ! q r, c = q * b + r /\ r < b) a).
eapply strong_induction.
```

You could also use more directly the `refine` tactic. This tactic is similar to the `apply` tactic.

```
Goal forall a b, b <> 0 -> exists ! q r, a = q * b + r /\ r < b.
refine (strong_induction _ _).
```

But the `induction` tactic already handles arbitrary induction principles.

```
Goal forall a b, b <> 0 -> exists ! q r, a = q * b + r /\ r < b.
induction a using strong_induction.
```

More on these tactics [here](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactic-index.html). You should probably use `induction` before `intro`-ing and `split`-ing.

Comment: "induction a using strong_induction" works great! On the other hand, the "change" tactic fails with "Error: Not convertible."

Comment: when the change is too complex, you can try with the `replace` tactic, which will ask for a proof of equality. `change` is just `replace` when the proof is trivially reflexivity.